# Facebook chatting—3rd party creating a chat conversation

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

Is it possible for a 3rd party to create a private Facebook chat conversation between 2 other people?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to use Facebook Chat between two non-friends (other than Group Chat). You can use a separate third party software to get chat running.